# Checking for Errors

Tags: python

How do I set a value to **only accept certain data in Python**? Like I am making a code for a colour identifier. I want my variable to only accept up to `FFFFFF` any nothing greater than that. The base-16 characters pretty much...**hex code**.

The reason I am trying to do this is because if a user enters in a value like `GGGGGG` it will give them a **Script Error**, which actually makes me look incompetent (which I might be, but I do not want to look like I am). And also, if they enter in special characters like F1F2G% it will mess up too. In addition, if they leave the box blank, it also gives a Script Error.

I want to avoid those errors. Does anyone know of a good way?

Comment: How are you accepting input currently? What are you doing to validate your input currently?

Comment: Can you use a try/catch block?

Comment: Is the input a character string?

Comment: I am freely accepting input right now. If a user enters something, either it is the right information, or the Script just crashes. That is what I am trying to fix now. The one and only limiter is this:

colour = form["colour"].value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
try:
    val = int(hex_val, 16)
except ValueError:
    # Not a valid hex value

if val > int("FFFFFF", 16):
    # Value is too large
```

Comment: This is the way to do it, also make the comparisons you want with the value and raise a manual exception if it's not right.

Comment: Because 0xFFFFFF is too mainstream?

Comment: Just for completeness, you should probably check to make sure `val >=0`

Comment: except ValueError:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I do not know why I keep getting that?

Comment: @AjEntity -- The comments `#Not a valid hex value` and `# Value is too large` are for you to take some sort of action.  You need to put code in there, but that code depends on how you want to handle the error.

Comment: http://www.2shared.com/file/ioE6qsWJ/hexExplore.html

That is my file if you need to see it in case my explanation is not complete.

Comment: @mgilson Ohhh. I knew they were comments, but I did not know that I needed to put a code in there. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @AjEntity If Amber's answer solved your problem you should [**accept it**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the checkmark next to her answer. This will give you and her some rep points and also mark this problem as solved.

Comment: colour = form["colour"].value
val = colour, 16

try:
    val = int(colour, 16)
except ValueError:
    print "Please type characters in the range of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and" + \
    " a,b,c,d,e,f."
    
if val > int("FFFFFF", 16):
    print "Please type in a Hex Value, which does not exceed FFFFFF"

else: 

I just wanted to show the code that actually ended up working for me. Had to do slight modifications. Just for reference for other users googling this.

After the 

else: 

comes the rest of my entire code excluding print "</body>" and the sort.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach assuming the input is a string:

```
import string

def check_HEX(input):
    for l in input:
        if l not in string.hexdigits:
            return False
    return True
```

gives:

```
print check_HEX('FFFFFF') # True
print check_HEX('FFFZFF') # False
print check_HEX(' ')      # False
print check_HEX('F1F2G%') # False
```

Comment: red_decimal = hexToInt (red)
green_decimal = hexToInt (green)
blue_decimal = hexToInt (blue)

These values conflict with this because I have Int and not string. Sorry for not specifying.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the regex facility in re.

```
val = val.upper()
seeker = re.compile("^[0-9A-F]{1,6}$")

if seeker.search(val):
    hexCode = int(val, 16)
    # process a good value
else:
    #bail
```

Comment: seeker = re.compile([^0-9A-F]{1,6}$)
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


That is the error I get from that?